# Source.pipe is not a function with redux-observable / rxjs/operators

Tags: react-native, redux, rxjs, reactive-programming, redux-observable

Handling a react-native redux-observable project (*sigh...).
On the configuration of the store it seems I have an error but for the life of my I cannot know why.

Getting the following screen on load.
[image]

The following is the configuration file: (Everything else is really standard)

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import { createEpicMiddleware, ofType, combineEpics } from 'redux-observable'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

import { 
    registerEmailEpic,
} from './actions'

import {
    masterReducer
} from './reducers';

const rootReducers = combineReducers({ masterReducer });
const rootEpics = combineEpics(registerEmailEpic);

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();

// App dev + prod middleware.
// The order matters.
let middleware = [
    thunk, 
    epicMiddleware,
    combineEpics,
    ofType
];

if (__DEV__) {
    const reduxImmutableStateInvariant = require('redux-immutable-state-invariant').default();
    middleware = [...middleware, reduxImmutableStateInvariant, logger];
} else {
    middleware = [...middleware];
}

export default function configureStore() {
    const configuredStore = createStore(
        rootReducers,
        composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
    );
    epicMiddleware.run(rootEpics);
    return configuredStore;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the store here except that we don't need ofType here.

For anyone else stuck with this, if you're using TypeScript you need to import the operators as such:

So where you use `map` or things like `debounce` you need to import them as such: `import { mapTo, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Then you can use them like so:

```
export const registerEmailEpic = (action$: any, state$: any): any => {
    return action$.pipe(
        ofType('PING'),
        delay(1000), // Asynchronously wait 1000ms then continue
        mapTo({ type: 'PONG' })
      )
}
```